# rewrite a union query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables which have the same structure, let’s say TA and TB. Most records  in TA and TB are the same. There are some records in TA not in TB and some in TB are not in TA. I just want get all the records from TA and TB without duplicity:

```
Select * from TA
Union
Select * from TB
```

This query does give me the results I want. But the performance is not good as in production, there are more than half million data in both tables. Is there a simple way to get all the records from both table? Both tables have an id column which has unique value and can be joined by.

Comment: I don't work with Oracle much, but I doubt you come up with a SQL statement that will improve how the optimizer handles this.   Why do you need a result set of 500,000+ rows?

Comment: @Sparky it's actually between 500K and 1000K records since each table has that many rows

Comment: If the ID's are the same in both tables are the values going to be the same?

Comment: That's why I wrote 500,000+ rows <grin>

Comment: @Sparky, the 500,000+ rows is part of other process. We need get this first.

Comment: @Conrad Frix, yes, if IDs in both table are the same, the whole records are the same

Comment: Gary than you can do what @Goat_CO put as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS` + `UNION ALL`:

```
Select * from TA
UNION ALL
Select * from TB where not exists (select * from TA where TA.KEY_ID = TB.KEY_ID)
```

This gets you all data in `TA` and non-duplicates from `TB`.

Comment: If you're going to do this, however, you'd need to add another `UNION ALL` to find all the rows in `TB` that are not in `TA` as well.

Comment: @JustinCave - Unless I am misreading you, that is what the third line does.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.ID,B.ID), COALESCE(A.field2,B.field2), etc.
FROM A
FULL JOIN B
 ON A.Id = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this faster is to use `UNION ALL` which as you said there are duplicates, is problematic.

`UNION` is extremely efficient, optimized, and simple. There is no better way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` is quite slow when it comes to excluding duplicates.
If you have a key on these tables try adding a `WHERE` clause to 2nd table to exclude duplicates. 
You would do it more intellegently, than db.